# How i can shift one row of data frame to first row?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, transfer, shift

How i can shift one raw of data frame to first raw, i want the id raw be the first raw. in R.

```
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species

5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2         setosa
4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2         setosa
4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2         setosa
4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2         setosa
5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2         setosa
id           A            B           C            D
```

Comment: what is the desired output? do you want the row in question to be the header?

Comment: yes i want to be header

Comment: For a given csv you can `data.table::fread("given.csv",skip=N)` where N is the desired number of lines to skip

Answer (score 1):

We can use `grepl` to create a logical vector based on the 'id' in 'Sepal.Length', then set the column names of the dataset by extracting that row while removing the row from the original dataset

```
i1 <- grepl("id", df1$Sepal.Length)
setNames(df1[!i1,], unlist(df1[i1,]))
#   id   A   B   C      D
#1 5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 setosa
#2 4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2 setosa
#3 4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 setosa
#4 4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2 setosa
#5 5.0 3.6 1.4 0.2 setosa
```

Comment: i did it but all elements convert to NA!! whats wrong!

Comment: @AgriiEnginee  Please check the `str` of your data.  I assumed that it is all `character` class

Comment: @AgriiEnginee  You can first convert your columns to `character` ie. `df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.character)`

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following (assuming your ID is the Nth row):

```
df <- iris # Example of data.frame
myIdrow <- 5 # as an example id row
df2 <- df[c(myIdrow, (1:nrow(df))[-myIdrow]), ]
```

Although I would recommend to have the ID as column name.

Comment: i want to id raw be a header raw